# Transparency affects anti-aliasing in version 13.2?

Tags: graphics, bugs, rendering, opacity, antialiasing

**Retrogression in version 12.2 or 12.1**

I am making an animation with transparency, antialiasing fails when the transparency reaches certain values, which brings a jitter. A minimalist example:

```
Graphics[{{Opacity[0.01],RGBColor[0.5,1,1],Disk[]},{Circle[],Line[CirclePoints[5]]}}]
Graphics[{{Opacity[0.05],RGBColor[0.1,0,0],Disk[]},{Circle[],Line[CirclePoints[5]]}}]

Manipulate[Graphics[{{Opacity[t],RGBColor[{5, 166, 238}/255.],Disk[]},{Circle[],Line[CirclePoints[5]]}},
  PlotRange->1.1],{t,0,0.3}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> 13.2.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)

Can you reproduce it, is there a workaround?

Comment: You could rasterize it at a high resolution as a workaround, e.g do `Rasterize[..., RasterSize->1024]`

Comment: Looks like an interesting quirk with DX.  Experimentally, you would need to keep the value of Opacity in the range of 0.012 to 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) option [`RenderingOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html) to directly control the anti-aliasing settings.

```
Style[
 Graphics[{{Opacity[0.05], RGBColor[0.1, 0, 0], Disk[]}, {Circle[], 
    Line[CirclePoints[5]]}}]
 , RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1.}
 ]
```

If you have a dedicated GPU that performs better than your integrated GPU then also try setting your dedicated GPU as the default renderer in your system settings for one of your system's supported `"3DRenderingEngine"`. Then use that engine to render the graphic.

For example, with your dedicated GPU set as the default for your system's `"Direct3D"` renderer,

```
Style[
 Graphics[{{Opacity[0.05], RGBColor[0.1, 0, 0], Disk[]}, {Circle[], 
    Line[CirclePoints[5]]}}]
 , RenderingOptions -> {
   "3DRenderingEngine" -> "Direct3D"
   , "HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1.
   }
 ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still a problem for me, the jitter can't be eliminated.